# Drawing D structure trees

Tags: syntax-trees

Can someone help me draw a D structure tree for: Is the cake certain to have been eaten by the students?

Also if you could explain the reasoning behind why its drawn like that so i could get some understanding

Comment: We generally avoid doing homework, because it sabotages your education.  If you tell us what you've come up with so far, there might be some helpful suggestions forthcoming.